# How can I scrape/mine/cajole/tickle data from a website (preferably) with OSX?

Tags: macos, website, html

I am trying to 'grab' data from a website.

Is there a way to just point a program at a URL and it grabs everything at that domain.  How should i go about this on OSX 10.5?  If really needed, I can use an ubuntu or windows box as a last resort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `wget` command which is [available for download for Mac OS X](http://wget.darwinports.com/) included with most Linux distributions to download the entire contents of a website, images, CSS, JavaScript, videos, Flash files, and all.

Once you have it, open a terminal.  You probably want to call it like this:

```
wget -r -l0 -k http://www.example.com/
```

That will download *everything* from `http://www.example.com/` accessible by links.  The `-r` option turns on recursive downloading, so it downloads more than just the home page.  The `-l` option sets how many pages deep it will look for links from and download, setting to `0` as I did will set it to go in as far as it can.  Note that if the website uses dynamic page generation that could download a lot, as there could be many URLs that point to the same or very similar content.  The `-k` command is optional, and will make `wget` convert all the links, image tags, etc. to the correct location on your local machine so you can view it with a web browser on your computer and it will work correctly.

Note that it will only download files from *www.example.com*, not any other domains.  If you need it to go to other domains, use the `-H` switch to turn that on and then use the option `-D` switch to define the other domains to download from (e.g. `-D comments.example.com,beta.example.com`).  Be careful, if you leave off the `-D` switch and set `-l` to `0`/infinite you could very well try and download the entire World Wide Web!

Another switch that might be helpful is the `-N` switch, which will set the timestamp on the local file to the time provided by the HTTP `Last-Modified` header on the server, and not download files that haven't been changed on subsequent downloads.

For more information, consult [the `wget` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).

Comment: OS X _does_ in fact include curl out of the box, which does a lot of the same stuff as wget.

Comment: @NReilingh: `curl` doesn't support recursive downloading.

Comment: [CocoaWget](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/24787/cocoawget) might be a bit easier to use, if not as flexible.